# Swift: How to build nested comment and replies feature like instagram

Tags: swift

Hi I have a question regarding on how to build Instagram-like comment feature as below.

[image]

The problem for me now is how to build UI for replies cell for each comment.

I thought about building with nested collectionView or nested tableViews, but I wasn't confident on what's the best way.

Two questions.

1. Should I work with tableview or collectionView in this case? I actually already built comment UI with collectionView. But I wasn't confident on how to build self-cell sizing in case when I have another nested collectionView for replies on comment collectionView.
2. If I'm to work with nested tableview(one for comment, and the other for replies), is it okay to build it this way? Is there any standard way to build comment replies UI on the industry?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be nesting any UITableView / UICollectionView, this will kill your performance.

The best way to approach this is to use a section for the top comment / cells for the replies.

Bonus point if you build this using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, UICollectionViewFlowLayout behavior in autolayout is completely broken.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I built it with UICollectionViewFlowLayout because I needed to support iOS 11. So have number of sections set up to number of comments. For each comment section, I add number of replies, right? 

Let's say I have comment sections. I didn't want to display replies, but I'd rather have "view more" button on comment, and when I tap "view more", I show the replies. But how can I achieve this TT?